# Subtract one hour from hms in R without generating negative values

Tags: r, timestamp, lubridate

How do I subtract one hour from an hms?
for example I have

```
hms("01:00:00")
```

and I want to convert it in 00:00:00

UPDATE:
When subtracting one hour from 00:45:00 for example, the result should be "01:45:00" and no negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
strptime("00:45:00", format = "%H:%M:%S") - 3600
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(lubridate)
out <- hms("01:00:00")
out@hour <- out@hour - 1
sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", out@hour, out@minute, seconds(out))
[1] "00:00:00"
```

---

We may use `as.ITime` and subtract 3600

```
 as.ITime("01:00:00") - 3600
[1] "00:00:00"
```

Comment: But then the output is 0 not "00:00:00"

Comment: @ncnc_2020 the output of `hms` from your post `hms("01:00:00")` is also a period object

Comment: I assumed that you are using `hms` from `lubridate`

Comment: I am, but still I would need at the end a chr

Comment: @ncnc_2020 try the update

Comment: @ncnc_2020 I showed two methods.  What is the issue now

Comment: The second method worked, thank you. The only thing is when u have a "00:59:59" you get negative values. I made it work for my case but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: @ncnc_2020 that is a problem in all the solutions you got here

Answer (score 2):

```
hms::hms(lubridate::hms("01:00:00") - lubridate::hours(1))
00:00:00
```

Comment: Hey Vinicius, do you know any way to subtract one hour without getting negative values? I mean  00:45:00 - 1hour = 01:45:00